# @PathVariable is giving a 404 error when appending a "/" before the path variable {}

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a simple Spring MVC code. I have setup the project using spring 4.3.6.RELEASE version. I have set up a controller `PageController.java` using `@Controller`. I am having problem with one of the urls in which I have used `@PathVariable`.

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/test2/{greeting}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView test2(@PathVariable("greeting") String greeting) {
    if(null == greeting) {
        greeting = "This is the second default message";
    }
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
    mv.addObject("greeting", greeting);
    return mv;
}
```

When I am removing the "/" from `value = "/test2/{greeting}` i.e. converting it to `value = "/test2{greeting}` it is working as expected. But I want to append the "/" as I plan to add more path and connect some more modules.

I am sharing the code below. Any help will be much appreciated.

I am able to work with `@RequestParam` fine using the same configuration.

PageController.java

```java
@Controller
public class PageController {
        
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test2/{greeting}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView test2(@PathVariable("greeting") String greeting) {
        if(null == greeting) {
            greeting = "This is the second default message";
        }
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("page");
        mv.addObject("greeting", greeting);
        return mv;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <!-- Configuring the front-controller -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  
  <!-- Configuring so that every request goes through the front controller -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = 
   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
   
   <context:component-scan base-package = "com.anirvana.onlineshopping.controller" />
   
   <bean id = "viewResolver"
      class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      
      <property name = "prefix" value = "WEB-INF/views/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
      
   </bean>
   
</beans>
```

page.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<c:set var="contextRoot" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Online Shopping</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${contextRoot} says - ${greeting} 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you, by any chance, have another controller with a similar path? e.g: "/test2/{hello}

Comment: No currently it is the only controller that I have in my project.

Comment: Can you at least try a newer 4.3.x version? 4.3.6 is much older than the current 4.3.23.

Comment: *Looks* like it should work. You could also try the `@GetMapping` shortcut instead of `@RequestMapping`, but they should be identical, just trying to workaround a possible bug in the latter. (Again, worth trying a newer 4.3.x)

Comment: I updated the version to 4.2.23 and also tried with the @GetMapping but the problem is persisting. I debugged the flow. I am able to retrieve the parameter passes in {greeting} and am able to generate the ModelAndView object. But the flow breaks as soon as the object is returned.

Comment: Oh, wait. So the URL does reach the code and pass the correct greeting string? I hadn't realized that was the case. It's the `return mv;` that isn't working?

Comment: Yes exactly. The ''' return mv ''' is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `{greeting}` in the statement `value = "/test2/{greeting}"` and pass a `@RequestParam` not a `@PathVariable`.